# Where to find the category page in Bosa Theme

Tags: theme-development, file-manager

I have a WP site based on the [Bosa Restaurant Cafe](https://bosathemes.com/bosa-restaurant-cafe/) theme.
I gave fully customized it by editing the php files, since it is easier for me to edit the files becaues the customizer don't have many options. I want to customize the category page for all but I can't find it. I don't have a `category.php` file, and when I create one i have to write the full code I just want to add a small thing.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/), if the `category.php` file doesn't exist, the theme will use `archive.php`; if there's no `archive.php` file, then it'll fall back to `index.php`.